# WSO2 Identity Server Email OTP using REST API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We are trying to use WSO2 IS Rest Api for users's authentication. Is there any way to enable email otp with Rest API authentication?

Comment: Can you explain a bit about your use case. Its not clear from your question

Comment: We are trying to authenticate users using WSO2 Rest Api api/identity/auth/v1.1/authenticate and we want to enable MFA with email OTP during authentication with this api.
Is there any way to enable it?

Comment: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/mfa/2fa-email-otp/

Comment: It works. But we want to email otp with rest api, not from application interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 does not support REST API based MFA (Email, SMS) as of now, but it's on the roadmap.

1. https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/11549
2. https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/11548

As a community user, you may use https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-otp-integration-endpoints. However it is not covered under WSO2 commercial support.